# Как открыть множество python файлов через bat файл одновременно?

Tags: python, windows, bat

У меня 46 пайтон файлов и их нужно одновременно открыть 1 батником, как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

```
start c:\Python38-32\python.exe d:\Coding\Python\Tkinter\test1\test1.py
start c:\Python38-32\python.exe d:\Coding\Python\Tkinter\test2\test2.py
```

Если в именах путей есть пробелы, то полный путь необходимо взять в кавычки.

Comment: А проще никак? не указывая путь к самому пайтону, батник в одной папке со скриптами

Comment: @Андрей если в ОС открытие файлов py забиндено на их выполнение, то можно убрать путь к самому Python. Тогда вид будет такой: `start d:\Coding\Python\Tkinter\test1\test1.py` . Можно попробовать ещё проще: `start test1.py` , если они все в одной папке.

Comment: то есть  start test1. py start test2.py и так далее? Так получается?

Comment: @Андрей , да, так