# Как запустить несколько python скриптов?

Tags: python, bat

У меня есть несколько питон скриптов,которые нужно запустить в cmd(не обязатнльно одновременно, но чтобы каждый работал в cmd).Как я понял следует использовать .bat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все верно, нужен файл `.bat`. Если в системе путь к интерпретатору указан в path, можно сделать так:

```
python first_script.py
python second_script.py
```

Только вместо first_script/second_script твои названия.

Comment: а они запустятся по-очереди да?

Comment: Да, в таком же порядке, как и в батнике

Comment: таак спасибо, а есть ли возможность запустить сразу несколько(так как у меня там бесконечные программы)

Comment: Можно использовать команду start, подробнее [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1148557/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-python-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-bat-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE).  Или использовать многопоточность в python